# Create a new Telegram channel and fix rights / permissions with TLSharp

Tags: c#, telegram, tlsharp

I can create a new channel like this, where client is a `TLSharp.Core.TelegramClient` authenticated and conected:

```
TeleSharp.TL.Channels.TLRequestCreateChannel newChannel = new 
TeleSharp.TL.Channels.TLRequestCreateChannel();
            newChannel.Megagroup = true;
            newChannel.Title = channelName;
            newChannel.About = channelDescription;
return await client.SendRequestAsync<TeleSharp.TL.TLUpdates>(newChannel);
```

Does anyone know how to modify this permissions?

I would need to allow `Add Users` and then deny `Send Stickers` and `Polls`

Thank you very much!!

In the image below I show the default permissions after creation:
[image: Telegram Channel Permissions]

Answer (score 1):

TLSharp seems no longer maintained.. Try [WTelegramClient](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient) instead

Comment: Thank you @wizou I will try the client!